# c# word-2007 add-in: get the path and filename of current opened wordfile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, add-in, word-2007

I am coding da latex-addin with visual studio 2008 for word 2007.

My question: how do I get the the current path and filename of the opened file?
example: If i open the *C:\edu\test.docx* with word 2007, my add-in have to get me "C:\edu\test.docx" shown in a MessageBox.

HOW does it work?? iam going mad.

I tryed methodes of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word or Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word, but i think these only get informations from new Objects, so these ist what iam looking for.

Does this path+filename exist in the System Properties? In google I didnt find any useful results.

thanks a lot

robert

Answer (score 4):

Though my answer is late enough to help you anymore, yet I shall put it in here to help someone else who comes along. In word 2007, within the add in you can call `Name` , `FullName` and `Path` properties of the active document as follows

```
        // Get the Active document 
        var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;

        MessageBox.Show("Document Name : " + doc.Name);
        MessageBox.Show("Document Full Name : " + doc.FullName);
        MessageBox.Show("Document Path : " + doc.Path);
```

if the document is saved, all three shall return documentName , documentName with path , path of documentonly, respectively. if the document is not saved, it shall show `Document1`, `Document1`, `(empty path)` respectively.